# Estimate the amount of atoms in the smallest speck of matter you can see with the naked eye

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atoms, estimation, vision, textbook-erratum

I am currently working through a physics text book at my own pace on Newtonian mechanics. I came across this question in the the chapter 1 problems and had a bit of trouble with it.

My biggest issue is that I can't seem to find a solid value for the smallest visible 'speck' of matter visible to the naked eye, nor do I really know if I am going about calculating it right.

The most general answer I found was 0.1 mm. I then calculated the volume of a sphere of radius 0.05 mm and simply assumed this to be the smallest object we can see. However after dividing the volume for an atom by this number I come out around $10^{18}$–$10^{15}$ atoms. The book however gives an answer of $10^{11}$–$10^{13}$ atoms.

Not quite sure where I am going wrong, sorry if this is a simple question I'm quite new to this subject.

Comment: 1) How did you transform volume to amount of atoms? 2) Why did you pick a sphere, and not just a disk-like volume?

Comment: What did you use for the volume of an atom?

Comment: The question as asked is completely nonsensical because the human eye is perfectly capable of seeing a single atom if it is illuminated properly. What we can't see is the physical size of an atom, but we can see it scattering light.

Comment: Starting with a 0.1mm cube I get roughly the same number of atoms that you do, so your arithmetic is correct. The conclusion is therefore that the book must be using a different criterion for what is visible to the naked eye. Since we don't know what criterion your book is using we can't help with your question.

Comment: Would you be willing to edit your question with the author & title of the textbook?

Comment: I deal with powder all the time.  On a very clean surface you can see a grain of 50 microns in diameter without too much trouble.  You start to really struggle around 10 microns.  If you shine a green laser through the air in a dark room you can "see" particles in the ~1 micron range reflecting the light.

Answer (score 1):

CuriousOne writes in a comment that single atom is visible "if it is illuminated properly," which is correct. It's possible to construct a trap for a single atom with transparent windows, and to illuminate that atom so that it fluoresces.  Note that this was impossible thirty years ago and is nontrivial today.

What your textbook author almost certainly has in mind is an order-of-magnitude estimate, sometimes known as a [Fermi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem), since Fermi was particularly incisive at choosing good ones.

First we'll want some estimate for the volume of an atom.  Hydrogen has a [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius) of about $0.5\rm\,Å$, which is probably a hard minimum for ordinary matter. A more typical [lattice constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_constant) might be $\rm5\,Å$. Let's lean towards the larger value: a single atom's volume in a solid is something like $1–100\times10^{-30}\rm\,m^3$.

Next, and what seems to be troubling you, is an estimate for size of a "smallest speck" of visible matter.  The eye deals not in sizes, but in [angular sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution); this is why you can resolve more detail in your back yard than you can on the giant planet Jupiter.  A typical angular resolution for a human eye is about one minute of arc, or 0.3 milliradians (this is the apparent diameter of a star on a clear night).  At a distance of 0.3 meters that resolution corresponds to about $\rm0.3\,m\cdot0.3\,mrad\approx0.1\,mm$, as you've said.  I'm personally pretty nearsighted, so with my glasses off I can focus on objects perhaps only 0.1 mm from my eye; that gains me a factor of three, which isn't much.

A cube 0.1 mm across has volume $10^{-12}\rm\,m^3$. (A sphere inscribed in a cube has the volume reduced by $\frac{4\pi}{3}\cdot\frac18 \approx \frac12$, which we don't care about.)  So that gives us $10^{16–18}$ atoms in our cube, which is consistent with your estimate.

It's possible that the author of the textbook was not thinking of naked-eye resolution, but rather visible-light resolution: because of diffraction of visible light, even with magnifying optics it is not possible to resolve objects smaller than about $\rm1\,\mu{m}$ (and then, probably, only in the blue). *That* size sphere has volume $10^{-18}\rm\,m^3$, and therefore contains $10^{10-12}$ atoms using your (correct) method.

Comment: I'm curious as to which textbook it is. Ambiguous, "Guess what I am thinking of" writing is frustrating to the beginning student of physics. Maybe this text has a general problem with that and is worth steering clear of.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks to answers certainly has cleared it up a bit. The textbook is 'Newtonian Mechanics' by A.P French if anyone is interested.